# Performance increase after error in PyOpenCl with Intel OpenCl

Tags: python, performance, opencl, intel, pyopencl

I've been trying to speed up my implementation of the Mandelbrot set using OpenCl via PyOpenCl. I now have some weird performance issues with Intel OpenCl compared to AMD APP.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 on an HP Elitebook 840 G1 with an Intel Core i7-4600U.

The main part is the function to calculate the number of iterations for a given point on the grid (image) is:

```
platforms = cl.get_platforms()
devs = platforms[1].get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.CPU)

def Mandelbrot(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xsize, ysize, maxit, col, image):
    ctx = cl.Context(devices = devs)
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

    mf = cl.mem_flags
    output_opencl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, image.nbytes)

    dx = (xmax - xmin) / xsize
    dy = (ymax - ymin) / ysize

    prg = cl.Program(ctx,code).build()

    prg.mandelbrot(queue, (xsize, ysize), None, np.float64(xmin), np.float64(ymax), 
               np.float64(dx), np.float64(dy), np.uint16(maxit), np.uint16(col), output_opencl)

    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, image, output_opencl).wait()
```

Here `platforms[0]` would be the AMD APP and `platforms[1]` is Intel OpenCl, the device is the Core i7 both times. `code` would be the kernel written in OpenCl C.

Using the Core i7 on the AMD APP this function clocks at around 0.075s for a 1024x1024 pixel image with an iteration depth of 200. Using Intel OpenCl the time is around 0.25s, which is unexpected, as the Intel OpenCl usually performs better with the Core i7.

Now I get a weird behaviour. If I let the program end in an error by changing anything in the function `Mandelbrot` (e.g. any syntax, arguments), run this in an IPython console and get an error message, correct the error and run it again, then the performance on the Intel OpenCl increases to 0.045s (factor of 5-6). After this, the performance is always better than with the AMD APP, until I restart the IPython console. If I run the program in the command line using `python3 file.py` the performance is bad. It only works if I let it run in the same IPython console, first ending in any error and then the correct one...

I really have no idea what could be causing such a strange error. Most likely some mistake with the Intel OpenCl runtime, though I wouldn't know where to begin looking...

Thank you very much

Comment: What are you timing? Is it the whole `Mandelbrot` function, or just the computation?

Comment: The whole `Mandelbrot` function, which includes creating context and everything and the actual computation.

Answer (score 0):

You are timing all of the initialisation routines, which include creating the OpenCL context, allocating memory, copying memory to and from host to the device (even though they are the same thing in this case, there is still a memcpy), and compiling the program.

All of this will dramatically affect the runtime you observe. In particular, compiling programs is expensive, and different vendors (Intel, AMD) will perform different program transformations and optimisation passes. This is likely where your first discrepancy is coming from (AMD appearing to be much faster than Intel).

The weird behaviour you are observing is probably due to the fact that some of these initialisation routines are being performed before being interrupted by your induced error. The second time you run the code from the same interpreter, those routines may not need to run again (compiled programs could be cached, memory allocations remain, threads haven't been destroyed etc), hence causing the much faster second run.

You could verify all of this by splitting your code to divide the initialisation of OpenCL and the actual computation. If you do this, you will likely see much more consistent results (for the computation).

When I want to benchmark OpenCL computation, I would typically write a program with this structure:

```
# Initialise OpenCL context, program, buffers etc

# Copy memory to device

# Run kernel once to 'warm-up'

# Start timing
# Run kernel several times in a loop
# Stop timing

# Read results back and verify

# De-initialise OpenCL
```

(Though depending on your use-case, you may wish to include data-transfer in the timing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, already helped a lot. I now did some more time measurements now. The calculation alone and transfering memory are as expected, what is slowing down the program is creating the context it seems. The line `ctx = cl.Context(devices = devs)` is taking up to 0.2 seconds on Intel OpenCl, whereas no time (10^-5s) on AMD APP. Once I let it run into an error on the same interpreter the time goes down to 10^-5 as well... Note though that if I just let the program run multiple times the time does not change. Only when I let it run into an error does the behaviour change.

Comment: So: Creating the context on the Intel OpenCL takes quite some time compared to on the AMD APP (0.2s vs 10^-5s). I don't know why this happens and haven't found anything on the internet. After any error in compiling the OpenCl C code in the same interpreter the behaviour changes and creating the context on Intel OpenCl works fast as expected. Only solution I've found to bypass the problem is creating the context outside of the function. Then every time I call the function it only has to do the calculations, which take no time. But as to why it takes ages to create context I still have no idea..

Comment: @somebody It could be doing lots of things - we just don't know (e.g. creating and pinning worker threads, reserving memory regions, setting up internal data structures, loading auxiliary libraries etc). This shouldn't matter though - you should only need to create the context once, and then re-use it throughout your program.